# DRF - make an resource alias /me for current user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to make a resource that will have /user/me url endpoint that will point to current user and behave exactly same as /user/< userid > ( e.g all post, put, delete request done to /user/me should work same way as /user/< userid > ). I see that there is a @detail_route decorator for custom routes, but it seems that inside it i will need to duplicate  code there , for each separate request method, which doesnt seem to be a good option. I just need to make an alias for current user.
Im talking about ModelViewSet

Comment: How have your constructed your views? Are you using ViewSets? Generic class-based views? Function-based view?

Comment: ModelViewSet. Updated the question

Comment: what do you mean by "`/user/me` url endpoint that will point to current user"?

Comment: @iulian ouch, SO eat some symbols.  I mean /user/me endpoint that will point to current user and have all other method that have /user/currentuserid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't tested this, as I don't use ViewSets myself, but I believe you could do something like this:

In your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework import routers

from . import views


router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/me/$', views.UserViewSet.as_view(), kwargs={'pk': 'me'}),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

In your `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('pk', None) == 'me':
            self.kwargs['pk'] = self.request.user.pk
        return super(UserViewSet, self).get_object()
```

Again, this is entirely untested, and entirely theoretical, but something of this sort should work.

Comment: Used similar approach. But modified only get_queryset method.

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        qs = Profile.objects.all()
        if self.kwargs.get("pk", "") == "me":
            self.kwargs['pk'] = user.profile.id
        return qs

Answer (score 0):

I too wanted a similar feature where I had a bunch of URLs such as:

- host_name/api/student/<pk>
- host_name/api/student/<pk>/something_else

and I wanted the user to be able to access any such URL by replacing  with me, and it would automatically substitute 'me' for that user's pk. So I used an improved verison of [@Joey Wilhelm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1971587/joey-wilhelm)'s answer.

urls.py:

```
# original:
path('api/', include(student_router.urls)),

# modified:
path('api/', include(student_router.urls), kwargs={'pk': 'me'}),
```

views.py:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # we do not want the 'pk' kwarg to appear in non-detail views,
    # since that will give us a "<view> got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'" error
    if not self.detail:
        kwargs.pop('pk', None)

    else:
        # self.request is not yet populated with the proper user details,
        # so initialize it the same way as in the super method
        req = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # replace 'pk' with the user's pk
        kwargs['pk'] = req.user.pk

    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```